# How to index and print columnnames based on dataframe cells matching specific conditions

Tags: r

I've got a coding problem, I'm not able to solve on my own, so I'd appreciate  any help from you. To summarise, I'd like to create a new colum attached to my dataframe listing the column names of those cells which match a specific condition (row by row). I have searched for solutions for a very long time, but I still haven't found the right one for me.

Let's say I got a dataframe like this:

```
a <- c(90, NA,20)
b <- c(NA, 89, 20)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
names(d) <- c("house", "cat")

  | house | cat
--|-------|----
1 | 90    | NA
--|-------|----
2 | NA    | 89
--|-------|----
3 | 20    | 20
```

I'd like to get a final data frame with a new colum, which lists all the column names of those cell values that are not NA. So, ideally it would look like this:

```
   | house | cat | newcol
---|-------|-----|--------
1  | 90    | NA  | house  
---|-------|-----|--------
2  | NA    | 89  | cat    
---|-------|-----|--------
3  | 20    | 20  | house, cat
```

I must admit that - even though I've been seaching this for about a week now - I have trouble indexing the cells and the columnames. I've tried a for loop and I've tried using apply. I've tried every one-bracket-, two-bracket-version I could think of. I tried to include which() into apply, i tried.. a lot.

Most of the time I adressed the rows within the apply function cause as I understand it, I want the function looping over the rows and finally write a new vector at the end of each row. But it didn't get me nowhere, one of the many versions was this one:

```
col <- colnames(d)[apply(d, 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x),arr.ind=T))]
```

But it prints an error: "Error in colnames(d)[apply(d, 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x), arr.ind = T))] : invalid subscript type 'list'"

So I tried addressing the columns, which didn't do it either...:

```
col <- colnames(d)[apply(d, 2, function(x) which(!is.na(x),arr.ind=T))]
col
[1] "house" NA      "cat"   NA
```

I also had the colname reference within apply, trying to row by row build vectors. (I've tried this also with print() or paste() around the colnamesindex):

```
similar <- c(similar, apply(d, 1, function(x) colnames(x)[x[!is.na(x)]]))
```

The last thing i tried was without a loop:

```
e <- which(!is.na(d),arr.ind=T)
list <- names(d[e[,2]])
list
[1] "house"   "house.1" "cat"     "cat.1"
```

But this code is running down the columns and the output doesn't allow me to match elements of the output with its corresponding row.

I'd very much appreciate your help. I feel like I'm not asking for a complicated thing to be done but still it's too complicated for me. (I'd like to add that I just started using R so my current workflow is still mostly google-trial and error.)

I'd be very happy to learn from you.
Thank you very much.
LK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it...

```
df$newcol <- apply(df,1,function(x) paste(names(df)[!is.na(x)],collapse=", "))

df
  house cat     newcol
1    90  NA      house
2    NA  89        cat
3    20  20 house, cat
```

Comment: Also `d$newcol <- apply(!is.na(d), 1, function(x) paste(names(d)[x], collapse=", "))`.

Comment: Thank you, both of you! The first solution doesn't look too different from one of my many attempts... I am very grateful to be able to continue now. It is frustrating though, I'd loved to solve this without having to bother you. Anyway, thank you very much!